# Intervention analysis with multiple time series of daily counts

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, intervention-analysis

I have daily time-series data over the same 10 year period for the number of visits of specific individuals to a certain website, i.e. number of visits per user per day. The visitors are from a specific geographical area and are effected by the same seasonal patterns (day of the week, holiday-effects, day of the month, yearly seasonality).

An intervention occurs on January 1st 2011. It would be expected to have a gradual increasing effect until January 1st 2012 and after that a constant effect. It would also be expected that only some users would be affected. I'm interested in classifying users based on wether or not they are affected, and by quantify the magnitude of effect.

This is in some respects longitudinal/oanel data and in others more like a multiple time-series problem. Either way I'm not sure were to begin formulating a solution. Any pointers or help is appreciated.

The data is such that we can know the following for every visitor:

1) Each visitor has at least one visit for at least 100 days.

2) The total number of visits for each user over the period is at least 500.

3) Each user has at least one visit prior to January 1st of 2009

4) Each user has at least one visit following January 1st 2013

The following graph gives a visual idea of the problem (here –20 users are shown, the dataset contains several thousand).

[image]